# Grouping data in a select box using jQuery and Backbone

Tags: jquery, html, json, backbone.js, marionette

I have a JSON object which populates a dropdown menu. This is a sample of the JSON:

```
{"dates":[
  {"dateDescription":"Jan 2008","month":1,"year":2008},
  {"dateDescription":"Feb 2008","month":2,"year":2008}
]}
```

Basically I have a few dozen rows, covering several years, so 12 rows for 2008, 2009 etc.

I'm looking for a way of grouping them, so all the dates for 2008 will appear in the drop down (like now) but above them will be a header saying 2008, if the user clicks the header it will basically select all of the 2008 options.

This is the code for my Combobox:

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="datedropdown">
  <% _.each(dates, function(item){ %>
    <option value="<%= item %>"><%= item %></option>
  <% });%>
</select>
```

I'm using Backbone & Marionette to query the JSON and populate the months and cannot change the JSON. This is the code to populate the months currently.

```
return Backbone.Model.extend({  
  url: "webapp/JSONDATA",
  loaded: false,
  defaults: function() {
    return {
      states: [],
      dates: []
    }
  },
  parse: function(data) {
    return {
      states: _.pluck(data.states, 'stateName'),
      dates: _.pluck(data.dates, 'dateDescription') //in the format Jan 2008
    }
  },

  initialize: function () {
    this.on('change', this.change);
    this.fetch();
  }
```

I'm also using Bootstrap for the drop downs and they offer 'optgroup' tag to add titles when doing the markup manually, but i can't work out how to do it dynamically and have it selectable.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of Underscore's [`groupBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) method to group objects by an attribute. The function in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LqrDL/3/) takes some JSON, groups it, and generates the HTML needed for a `<select>` dropdown. I'm not sure if this exactly what you're looking for, but hopefully the groupBy function can help in some way.

http://jsfiddle.net/LqrDL/3/

Comment: Up voted, but please put your answer (the relevant code, and an explanation of that code) into your answer; otherwise as soon as JS Fiddle falls over your answer becomes useless.

Comment: Hi, thats great i had something similar but yours looks like it's written better, what i'm trying to do though is have those year headers selectable - so when i user clicks '2008' all 3 dates are selected.